# Wordpress keeps "cleaning" my post format html

Tags: php, wordpress, wysiwyg

So here i find myself, again, struggling with wordpress wysiwyg editor.
a client of mine requested to migrate his website to WP. No probs, a breeze :).
Really was easy, migrated from one DB structure to the other, and everything went OK.

Now I have a problem. The old site, used an editor that added `<br`> and `<p>` tags to the content in order to format it (sounds legit to me). But wordpress will not allow these tags. whenever the client tries to edit a post, WP removes all the HTML tags it considers "illegal".

So I went on the search. First I tried to install some recommended plugins I found for this problem (such as  [this one](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/enable-raw-html-disable-corruption/)). Didn't work at all for me (for some others it did i believe)...

Then I found a post that told me to add a function to the function.php file which will remove the filters :

```
function mod_mce($initArray) {
$initArray['verify_html'] = false;
return $initArray;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'mod_mce');
```

and also this:

```
function my_tinymce( $init ) {
$ext = 'div[id|name|class|style]';

if ( isset( $init['extended_valid_elements'] ) ) {
    $init['extended_valid_elements'] .= ',' . $ext;
} else {
    $init['extended_valid_elements'] = $ext;
}
 return $init;
} 
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_tinymce' );
```

functions from [this thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/visual-editor-now-strips-html-comments-new-in-32).
Nope, didn't work also...

Someone - any idea? It seems so silly, but there is so much debate around this subject...
Thanks

Comment: I thought about going all over the DB and replacing the <br> and <p> tags to something else, but is there no simpler solution?

Comment: I created a little WP plugin for myself, which disabled some functions: `wpautop`, `wp_nop`, `wptexturizer`, `capital_P_dangit` by modifying the wordpress source code ... http://simpleddl.coolpage.biz/wpautop-killer.zip

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for sharing, but still the same behavior.   I managed to solve it using this plugin eventually : http://rubayathasan.com/wordpress/plugin/enabling-line-break-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this to remove filters that [wpautop](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop) uses to filter content and excerpt, just put these in your funcions.php file

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

**Reference: [WordPess wpautop](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop)**

To allow older content with p and br to load in tinyMCE

```
function my_tinymce_config( $init ) {
    $init['remove_linebreaks'] = false; 
    $init['convert_newlines_to_brs'] = true; 
    $init['remove_redundant_brs'] = false; 
    return $init;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_tinymce_config');
```

**Reference: [tinyMCE Configuration](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration)** look at Cleanup/Output and try playing with these.

Another way could be helpful [Reference](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3averify_html)

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    verify_html : false
});
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the comment. I added the suggested code to functions.php, but when I switch between the HTML and Visual tabs, still all <BR> and <P> tags are removed :/ ... Do I understand correctly and the code should have prevented this behavior?

Comment: I didn't try to apply the js code though - could you please direct me to where the mce config file is hidden in WP? couldn't find it...

Comment: You can put tinyMCE.init({...}) inside your main jsfile.

Comment: See 'Example of TinyMCE configuration' at http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration